# ¿Como trabajar con SimpleMembership en ASP.Net MVC en MySql? Para denegar y permitir el acceso a usuarios

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, login

Cuando uno crea un proyecto en asp.net desde visual studio, y se elege la opción aplicación web, le genera unos archivos que permite colocar unos encabezados que son los siguientes:

```
     [Authorize]
     [InitializeSimpleMembership]
```

Estos me permite validar si el usuario está logueado para permitir el acceso a las vistas.

Mi pregunta es¿Como puedo hacer esto mismo, pero cuando creo un proyecto vacio/blanco?
He visto algunos ejemplos como lo describe en el siguiente link:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/4b0136/working-with-simplemembership-in-asp-net-mvc/

pero resulta que en mi caso no funciona, y lo mas probable sea porque el ejemplo es para SQLSERVER, y yo estoy usando MySql.

Al tratar de probar tal como muestra el ejemplo del link, me da el siguiente error:

No se puede abrir la base de datos "usuario_bd" solicitada por el inicio de sesión. Error de inicio de sesión

este error da en la vista del login que es así:

```
 public ActionResult Login()
    {
        if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
        {
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MembershipDbContext", "usuarios", "password", "email", autoCreateTables: true);                
        }         
        return View();
    }
```

y en la webconfig es así:

```
 <add name="MembershipDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=usuario_bd;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

pero cuando lo intento probar de esta forma en la webconfig:

```
 <add name="MembershipDbContext" connectionString="SERVER=150.011.252.252;Initial Catalog=secure_login;Integrated Security=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

me sale el siguiente error:

> Authentication to host '150.011.252.252' for user 'auth_windows' using method 'authentication_windows_client' failed with message: Access denied for user 'auth_windows'@'186-106-11-194.baf.movistar.cl' (using password: NO)

Me gustaría saber cual sería la solución a esto. En todo caso, el objetivo es poder restringir usuarios, no permitiendo el acceso a vistas o paginas si no está logueado. Idealmente sería tener roles, pero ya sería un tema aparte.

Comment: Hola Danilo, ¿has probado autenticarte con esas mismas credenciales directamente en el manejador de base de datos? De igual forma revisa si la autenticación de Windows la tienes activa en tu manejador, [aquí la documentación oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.5/en/windows-authentication-plugin-installation.html).

Comment: @Flxtr, como que forma te refieres??antiguamente usaba un archivo o una clase para hacer la conección, y validaba si existía el usuario con su contraseña ingresada a la base de datos, usando los encabezados que mencione antes para la autentificacion, pero con un proyecto no vacio, sino con aplicación web.

Comment: Con el comentario "*de igual forma*" me refería a que también revisarás si en tu manejador de base de datos, y saber si la autenticación de Windows está habilitada

Comment: arregle el problema, en la webconfig debo colocar:     <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" timeout="2880"/>

lo del connectionString esta demas, y en el controller, donde me logueo, debo colocar :

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user, false);

Comment: Ah muy bien, ponlo como respuesta para que vaya creciendo la base de conocimientos :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arreglé el problema, en el archivo `web.config` debo colocar:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" timeout="2880"/>
```

Lo del `connectionString` está de más, y en el `Controller`, donde me logueo, debo colocar :

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user, false)
```

Comment: marca esta pregunta con el check verde para que ayudes a mantener la salud del sitio (% de respuestas resueltas) Saludos hermano :D

Answer (score 0):

Debes colocar en tu menustrip esta codigo:

Saludos.

```
    Private Sub CargarDatosToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CargarDatosToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Form2.MdiParent = Me
        Me.MenuStrip.Enabled = False
        Form2.Show()
        Form2.Focus()
    End Sub
```